# Replace first and last character in string if the character is X

Tags: python

I want to replace the double quotes only if the string starts and ends with double quotes. Below are some examples:

```
str = '"hello"'
```

would become

```
str = 'hello'
```

but

```
str = 'hello"'
```

would stay as is because it only ends with double quotes.
What I do now is

```
if str.startswith('"') and str.endswith('"'):
    str = str[1:-1]
```

but I'm pretty sure there's a better way of doing this that I can't figure out.

Comment: Maybe use regex?

Comment: Your way is perfect.

Comment: @ppwater I tried but I don't understand regex enough to make something that works.

Comment: so, can you use regex?

Comment: @ppwater yes, I can use it. I searched for plenty of other posts but nothing fits what I need. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

A simple other way would be:

```
if str and str[0] == str[-1] == '"':
    str = str[1:-1]
```

Comment: That's cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: @BananaMaster don't forget to check for empty string. `startswith` works fine with them but `str[0]` will raise an exception